# Element text content not visible in horizontally arranged mixed inline elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of images rendered horizontally with `display:inline` and various other CSS to make it work. At the end of the line of images, I want to include a portion of text. The horizontal arrangement of the images is working fine, but when I add this 'portion of text' at the end, I can't seem to get it to be visible.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thgLp/2/).

The last `<li>` element is the element I'm using to append the text. Despite reinstating `font-size`, `white-space` and `line-height` to their normal settings, the paragraph text below just won't show itself.

With the current setup, what is hiding the text? How can I make this work?

The horizontal images are displaying perfectly in most browsers I've tested, so I don't want to change any of the other list items style properties; just the `<li class="page">` and any children.

**EDIT**:

I'm aware that I have set my `font-size` to `0` on the `<ul>` tag. This is needed, however, as inline elements need to be touching each other. The only way to do this is by setting `font-size` and `line-height` to zero.

I can see now that this is a `font-size` issue, but I need to keep any CSS changes/additions to the `<li class="page">` element and lower. Not to mention keeping my font-sizing in `em's`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a [working fiddle with the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/qwwGR/).

To summarize what was going on here, you were setting `font-size: 0;` on the `ul` selector, then trying to reset the `font-size` back on the `li` selector.

I solved the problem by moving `font-size: 0;` down to the `ul li` selector, then placing the `font-size: 1em;` on the `ul > li.page` selector.

Your error was trying to reset the font on a child of `ul`, while `ul` (the parent) still dictated that `font-size` will be `0`.

Here are the relevant parts of the CSS that made it work:

```
ul{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;

}

ul li{

  display:inline;
  font-size: 0;
  height:100%;

}

ul li img{

  max-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  width:auto !important;

}

ul > li.page{

  font-size:1em;

}

ul > li > div{

 display:inline-block;
 width:40%;
 white-space:normal;
 line-height:1;
 vertical-align:top;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great solution. First time in a long while that I've actually had someone *solve* a tangible problem for me on SO instead of creating new ones. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have given `font-size:0` for `ul`. Please Remove it then it will work!!

Then you can see the text also!! ;)

Comment: Your solution completely breaks my horizontal image layout because I depend on a `font-size:0` for all the other items. They now appear with a space between them (because of the way the browser treats inline elements). I do concede, however, that this is clearly a `font-size` issue, it's just that I need to keep my font-sizing in `em's` in order to retain relative sizing.

Answer (score 0):

In your ul tag

```
ul{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;


}
```

you have given `font-size:0px`
so just remove it,your text will appear at the right side of images